# Is there a function in urllib or the stdlib that recognizes a SSH-like URL vs. a local path?

Tags: python, parsing, urllib, parse-url

`rsync` recognizes if a destination is local `rsync a/ /local/path/`  or if it is remote `rsync a/ user@example.com:/path/to/`.

**Is there a similar URL parsing tool, built-in in Python's stdlib?**

The key thing with `rsync` or `scp` is that we don't want to prepend a `ssh://`, it *automatically* parses it as local or remote, that's the requirement I have.

`urllib.parse` does not seem to be what I'm looking for:

```
import urllib.parse
print(urllib.parse.urlsplit('user@host.com:/home'))  # SplitResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='user@host.com:/home', query='', fragment='')
print(urllib.parse.urlsplit('./slash@host.com:/home')) # could be both a local path with @ and : in dirname
print(urllib.parse.urlsplit('./slash@host.com:/home')) # or a remote with valid unix username "./slash"
```

Note: [SCP's implementation](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/816036f142ecd284c12bb3685ae316a68d2ef190/misc.c#L882) and [IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04) about this.